# Running regularized logistic regressions on very large datasets

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, lasso, regularization

I want to run a regularized logistic regression on a dataset with 25 million observations and about a 1000 mostly non-sparse columns with non-ignorable weights.

My first choice would be BayesGLM, but I'm sure that isn't remotely close to computationally feasible. I was looking into the LASSO/ElasticNet implementations in SciPi and it doesn't seem to have the ability to take weighted data. Does anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)

Comment: I'm not really sure that R can really handle data that size particularly well

Comment: Hmm... [biglars](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglars/index.html) uses the transparent-flat-file-storage package [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) to get around that difficulty. Maybe we need a bigglmnet package. I don't know your R hacking skill level; it's within my capabilities, but I have other things on my to-do list right now...

Comment: The latest Liblinear can handle this problem easily. you can search liblinear via Google.